# How to request changes on a PR as the author?

Tags: github, pull-request

I authored a PR to a repository on GitHub. My coworkers requested some changes and another coworker implemented those. BUT, I just found another bug. Since the coworkers who requested the changes approved the PR, it will probably be merged *broken*.

Is there a way I can block the PR and request changes again?

Comment: Did you try just pushing the latest version of your branch up with the fixes?

Comment: @mason Yeah it was an emergency and the branch got merged, and we had to revert it now. I wasn't fast enough and I figured asking on SO might be the best way to find out. I'll leave this question up for the future.